# List indices must be integers, not tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been given a .mat file which is `1024*1024*360` i.e., a 3D object. I have divided the data in to three .mat files A,B and C. All three of them are `1024*1024*120` . I am loading them to a matrix 'mat' which is `1024*360` . I am loading each one of them one by one and then deleting them to make space. Basically it's just a 2D slice of the 3D object at the point 240. Later I am trying to plot the image. Following is my code :

```
import scipy.io 

import numpy as np
mat = np.zeros((1024,360))

x = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/imaging/Desktop/PRAKRITI/Project/A.mat')  
x = x.values()           
mat[:,0:120]= x[240,:,:]
del x


y = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/imaging/Desktop/PRAKRITI/Project/B.mat')
y = y.values()
mat[:,120:240]= y[240,:,:]
del y


z = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/imaging/Desktop/PRAKRITI/Project/C.mat')
z = z.values()
mat[:,240:360]= z[240,:,:]
del z


import matplotlib.py as plt
imageplot = plt.imshow(matrix)
```

I am getting this error :

```
mat[:,0:120]= x[240,:,:]
TypeError: List indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you expect `x = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/imaging/Desktop/PRAKRITI/Project/A.mat'); x = x.values()` to produce?

Comment: It produces all the values inside A when I run it. But I want all those values to be loaded in to the matrix mat.

Comment: Can you isolate whether `mat[:,0:120]` or `x[240,:,:]` is the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mat[:,0:120]= x[240,:,0]` ?

Comment: I think x[240,:,:] itself is the problem as when I try to print it alone, it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a numpy array from the original x matrix.
This is why the normal python array doesn't accept the numpy type fancy indexing, like matrix[x,y,z] only like matrix[x][y][z].

```
import scipy.io 

import numpy as np
mat = np.zeros((1024,360))

x = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/imaging/Desktop/PRAKRITI/Project/A.mat')  
x = np.array((x.values()))
mat[:,0:120]= x[240,:,:]
del x


y = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/imaging/Desktop/PRAKRITI/Project/B.mat')
y = np.array((y.values()))
mat[:,120:240]= y[240,:,:]
del y


z = scipy.io.loadmat('/home/imaging/Desktop/PRAKRITI/Project/C.mat')
z = np.array((z.values()))
mat[:,240:360]= z[240,:,:]
del z


import matplotlib.py as plt
imageplot = plt.imshow(matrix)
```

Alternately you can use `x[240][:][:]` instead of `x[240,:,:]`

**Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)**

> ***continuing:***

Because the following code worked fine, i guess the problem is somewhere at the loaded matrixs' dimensions i.e. x.values() etc. So please check it first, with print x.shape().

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.zeros((1024,360))
x = np.zeros((1024,1024,120))

mat[:,0:120] = x[240,:,:]

print mat

[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/prakriti/Project/s.py", line 8, in <module>
        mat[:,0:119]= x[240,:,:]
    IndexError: invalid index

Comment: See the answer continuation.